# Is it possible to create a procedure with ANALYZE table instruction?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to call procedure to analyze table by name.
example: `call schema_name.analyze('table_name')`.
I've created procedure, but I'm gettin an error

> ERROR: relation "x" does not exist.

How to deal with it?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE schema_name.analyze(IN x VARCHAR)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
begin
    analyze x;
END;
$$;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.analyze_test(x character varying)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
begin
    EXECUTE 'analyze ' || quote_ident(x);
END;
$procedure$
```

Since you are doing dynamic naming use `EXECUTE`. Then `quote_ident() to get the passed in name correctly quoted.

**UPDATE**

Example of why `quote_ident()` is important:

```
create table "MixedCase" (id int);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.analyze_test(x character varying)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
begin
    EXECUTE 'analyze ' || x;
END;
$procedure$

call analyze_test('MixedCase');
ERROR:  relation "mixedcase" does not exist
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "analyze MixedCase"
PL/pgSQL function analyze_test(character varying) line 3 at EXECUTE

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.analyze_test(x character varying)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
begin
    EXECUTE 'analyze ' || quote_ident(x);
END;
$procedure$

call analyze_test('MixedCase');
CALL
```

**UPDATE 2**

To have a procedure or function run with the privileges of the user that created it use `SECURITY DEFINER`. See section at bottom of this page:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html

> Writing SECURITY DEFINER Functions Safely

for the do's and don'ts.

Here is original function with `SECURITY DEFINER`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.analyze_test(x character varying)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER
AS $procedure$
begin
    EXECUTE 'analyze ' || quote_ident(x);
END;
$procedure$
```

Comment: Thank you. 
If works for me even without quote_ident(), I'm passing call analyze_test('table_name').

Comment: I would still recommend using  `quote_ident()`. It will deal with strings passed in that have mixed case or spaces that would otherwise be folded to lower case or fail. For more information see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html).

Comment: See **UPDATE**.

Comment: Hmm, I've found out that I'm getting a notification during execution
**skipping "table" --- only table or database owner can analyze it.**
How can I prevent this and run analyze for diffrent users?

Comment: The notification would be?

Comment: See **UPDATE 2**.